# Permission Error while updating tweepy to 2.1

Tags: tweepy

I want to update my tweepy to 2.1 using

```
pip install tweepy --upgrade
```

but I get a permission error

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg'
```

I've searched around but have no idea how to resolve this..
Could anyone please please help me out? :(
thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run pip using `sudo`, as you're installing Tweepy in a system path.

Your command should look like this: `sudo pip install tweepy --upgrade`